# Caesar cipher that scales over a certain phrase by it's length is not working

Tags: python

I am making a Caesar cipher that scales over a certain phrase by the number of letters inputted but I cannot get my for loop to work.

```py
def encipher(word, numberToRotate):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        encryptedWord = ord(i) + numberToRotate
        if ord(i) <= ord("z") and ord(i) >= ord("a"):
            while encryptedWord > ord("z"):
                encryptedWord -= 26
            return chr(encryptedWord)
        elif ord(i) <= ord("Z") and ord(i) >= ord("A"):
            while encryptedWord > ord("Z"):
                encryptedWord -= 26
            return chr(encryptedWord)
        else:
            return i
```

Whenever I try to run this code, I get an error:

```
encryptedWord = ord(i) + numberToRotate
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

Can anybody tell me why this happens and how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

Your error says *"ord() expected string of length 1, but int found."* This means you passed an `int` to the `ord` function instead of the single character (`str` of length 1) it expects. This happens everywhere in your loop where you call `ord(i)` because `i` is an integer. `i` is the **position** of the character in the string, instead of the character itself.

Here are two ways to use a for loop to use each character in a string:

```py
theString = "The String"

# Your for loop iterates over indices of the
# string (0, 1, 2, etc.), like this: 
# i is an integer
for i in range(len(theString)):
  character = theString[i] # Get the character at position i
  print(f"{character} (position {i}): {ord(character)}")

  # print(ord(i)) will not work, since i is an int

# You can iterate over each individual character
# in the string like this:
for character in theString:
  print(f"{character}: {ord(character)}")
```

Notice how in both loops, we pass a single character (`str` of length 1) to the `ord` function instead of an integer. `ord` will the work as expected.